# Without sending any value password is automatically updating?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a user authentication system where user needs to verify first with otp after then user can login but the problem is while updating user verified status password is also updating automatically. I can't figure out the problem why is this happening. I sharing my code anyone help me with this

## Here is my verify and login controller

`

```
const verifyUser = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let minutes = 10;
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let otpTime;
  let otpFromDatabase;
  const { otp } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  if (!user) {
   res.status(404);
   throw new Error("User not found");
  }
 otpTime = new Date(user.otpTime).getTime();
 otpFromDatabase = user.otp;
 console.log("Time-Diff", now - otpTime > minutes * 60 * 1000);
 console.log("Time-Diff 2", now - otpTime);
 if (now - otpTime > minutes * 60 * 1000) {
  user.isOtpExpired = true;
  const otpExpiredUpdateUser = await user.save();
  res.json({
   otpTime: otpExpiredUpdateUser.otpTime,
   otpFromDatabase: otpExpiredUpdateUser.otp,
   otpExpired:otpExpiredUpdateUser.isOtpExpired,
  });
 } else {
   if (otpFromDatabase !== otp) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please enter a valid OTP");
   } else {
    user.isVerified = true;
    const verifiedUser = await user.save();
    res.json({
    _id: verifiedUser._id,
    name: verifiedUser.name,
    email: verifiedUser.email,
    token: generateToken(verifiedUser._id),
   });
  }
}});

const loginUser = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 const { email, password } = req.body;
 let verifiedUser;
 let matchUserPassword;
 const user = await User.findOne({ email });
 if (user) {
  verifiedUser = user.isVerified;
  matchUserPassword = await user.matchPassword(password);
  console.log(verifiedUser);
  console.log(matchUserPassword);
 }
 if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
  if (verifiedUser) {
   res.json({
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    token: generateToken(user._id),
   });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please verify the email!");
  }
 } else {
  res.status(401);
  throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
 }});
```

### I am also sharing the my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        mobile_number: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        otp: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        isOtpExpired: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: true,
        },
        otpTime: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        },
        isVerified: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: {
            createdAt: "created_at",
            updatedAt: "modified_at",
        },
    }
);

userSchema.methods.matchPassword =
    async function (enteredPassword) {
        return await bcrypt.compare(
            enteredPassword,
            this.password
        );
    };

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified) {
        next();
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(
        this.password,
        salt
    );
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I want only the fields should be updated that I mentioned in my code not other just like password

Comment: What the value of password is changed to?

Comment: @Konrad I use bcrypt to hash the password I dont know after running verify route what the password became but I taken the screenshot of previous record and making comparison  Iam seeing its some how changes

Comment: What does `matchPassword` do?

Comment: @Konrad matchPassword method is written in my schema which is basically doing comparison between two passwords

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
   if (!this.isModified) {
       next();
   }

   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
   this.password = await bcrypt.hash(
      this.password,
       salt
   );
});
```

You are hashing and salting the password every time the document is modified because `if (!this.isModified){next();}` means only pass execution to `next()` middleware when the document has not been modified. In other words, if the document has been modified hash and salt the password. I presume this is not your intention. If your intention is to only hash and salt the password when the value of the `password` property in your model changes you will need to pass that to the `isModified` method like so:

```
if (!this.isModified('password')) {
   next();
}
```

As per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.isModified()).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer i solve this problem by $set method